# Multithreading and Synchronization with Thread preemption

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Suppose I have the following piece of code

```
public synchronized void method()
{
    if(something == null)
    {
        something = new SomeThing();
    }
    //do something 
}
```

Now suppose in a multithreaded environment, one thread [Thread 1] enters the method and was preempted just after it executed the `new Something();` but before it was able to assign it to `something`. Then another thread [Thread 2] also tries to call the method. What exactly happens now? What happens to the lock that Thread 1 had acquired? Will Thread 1's steps be rolled back?

Comment: Synchronization is not like a transaction, there is no way to roll something back. How would you roll back if there was a file deleted or a UDP datagram sent in that block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thread1 did not give up the lock, so it still owns it. When Thread2 prepares to take the lock it will discover that it has to wait and enter a `BLOCKED` state. The next time the OS schedules Thread1 it will finish execution and release the lock. This allows Thread2 to be schedulable again.

Answer (score 3):

Thread 2 will not be able to enter the method until Thread 1 has exited it because it is synchronized.

Eventually the scheduler will get around to continuing with Thread 1, Thread 1 will execute new Something() and exit the method. Then, Thread 2 will be able to enter the function with the new Something() constructed.

The whole idea of the lock is that Thread 1 does not lose it until it is done with it. Thread 1 unlocks when it exits method(), then Thread 2 is able to acquire it.

Comment: There is a way to temporarily "lose" a lock in a synchronized block, though. Call `Object.wait()`.